# Rails rspec expects Admin::PostsController, which is there

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, admin

I have a file `app/controllers/admin/posts_controller.rb`

```
class Admin::PostsController < ApplicationController
  layout 'admin'

  # GET /admin/posts
  def index
     @pposts = Post.paginate :page => params[:page], :order => 'created_at DESC'
  end
  # ...Many more standard CRUD/REST methods...
end
```

And an rspec test `spec/controllers/admin/posts_controller_spec.rb`

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Admin::PostsController do

  describe "GET 'index'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'index'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
  #...many more test for all CRUD/REST methods
end
```

However, running that spec throws an error. I have no idea what that error means, nor how to start solving it.

```
/home/...../active_support/dependencies.rb:492:in `load_missing_constant': Expected /home/...../app/controllers/admin/posts_controller.rb to define Admin::PostsController (LoadError)
```

I may have it all set up wrong, or may be doing something really silly, but all I want is my CRUD actions on /admin, with separate before filters and a separate layout. And to test these controllers.

**EDIT** ZOMG, made a terrible copy-paste error into this SO posting. The controller was PostsController, not the PagesController that I pasted into there. Problem still stands, as my code is correct, just the SO post, here was wrong.

Comment: Everything looks right to me. Are you doing anything unusual in `spec_helper`?

Comment: @zetetic, can you turn this into an answer, it was the spec_helper, with spork-config that caused the problems. Then I can accept that answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks right to me. Are you doing anything unusual in spec_helper?

Comment: I was, indeed. I had spork set up after http://railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#code:spork_spec_helper

Answer (score 1):

Your file posts_controller.rb should define the class Admin::PostsController, but it is defining Admin::PagesController.

Was it a copy & paste? :-)

Comment: Yes, but it was a bad copy-paste into the SO post. My code is actually correct. Just confirmed. And again. To not look a fool: again. It is. Will edit question. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of trial and error gave me:

describe Admin::PostsController do
   end

should be

describe "Admin::PostsController" do
   end

I have no idea why, since the whole Rails module magic is a bit over my head here. But I suspect it is due to the autoloading that does expect a string, and not a class+module here.

**EDIT** Allthough this removes the error, it merely introduces a similar problem: @controller is not defined in this case. Making it impossible to test the controller at all :). Stay tuned...

Answer (score -3):

Berkes, you're not supposed to put the controller file in a sub-folder, meaning the files should reside at

```
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
```

and

```
spec/controllers/posts_controller_spec.rb
```

Once you get this done, to you need to add a method call "render_views" in you spec just after the "describe Admin::PostsController do" as follows:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Admin::PostsController do
  render_views

  describe "GET 'index'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'index'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
  #...many more test for all CRUD/REST methods
end
```

Comment: Someone -1ed this? Why? I am curious, what is wrong with Tsega's answer?

Comment: Also, It was rails generate that made these subdirectories. Is running Rails generage controller admin/foo wrong?

Comment: I don´t know why to vote down, but his answere is not correct once you can, indeed, use subdirs.

Comment: Ricardo you might be right, I'm not an expert in rails yet, but I've never seen a rails app with controllers in subdirectories. Berkes just try my suggestion and you will see that it works correctly.

Comment: @tsega: putting controllers in subdirectories is the convention by which Rails implements namespacing, i.e. `Admin::PostsController` is expected to be defined in `app/controllers/admin/posts_controller.rb`

Comment: I confirmed that moving the controllers or specs to a lower directory makes no difference.